# Nodejs modular programming, json error

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am new to Nodejs.  I am actually writing a code to just display a name on my browser window.  There are basically 4 files config.js, rootstudent.js, servicestudent.js and sqlstudent.js.  I tried the approach of splitting the coe because I had read that when doing big projects its advised to split up the code.

here is my config.js

```
var express = require('express');
var route=require('./routestudent');
var app = express();
var port = 5000;
route.studentRoutes(app);
var server = app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server is running on port '+port);
});
```

routestudent.js

```
var express = require('express');
var service=require('./servicestudent');
module.exports={
studentRoutes:function(app){
    app.get('/allData',function(request,response){
        service.getAllData(function(records){
            response.json({data:records.data});
        });
    });
 }
}
```

servicestudent.js

```
var express = require('express');
var sql=require('./sqlstudent');
module.exports={
    getAllData:function(records){
        return (sql.fetchData());
    }
}
```

sqlstudent.js

```
module.exports={
    fetchData:function(err){
        if(err)
         console.log(err);
        else{
            return json({name : " praveen "});
        }
    }
}
```

I am also attaching the error I got in browser window [image: error message]

Kindly help in identifying, where I have gone wrong..

Comment: In `fetchData` function you need to return data directly like `return {x:y};`.Also `getAllData()` is returning data so in `routestudent.js` it will be like `var records = service.getAllData();`

Comment: Hi Sarju, I changed accordingly.  Now in browser window it keeps on loading...

Comment: you have to add `response.status(200).send(records);` after `var records = service.getAllData();`

Comment: Tnx Sarju that worked.  But in console i get some errors, dont you think there sohuld be a callback function within var records = service.getAllData();  ?

Comment: Hi praveen I have added answer with callback implementation.If that works for you then you can accept that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

routestudent.js

```
var express = require('express');
var service=require('./servicestudent');
module.exports={
studentRoutes:function(app){
    app.get('/allData',function(request,response){
        service.getAllData(function(records){
            response.status(200).send({data:records});
        });
    });
 }
}
```

servicestudent.js

```
var express = require('express');
var sql=require('./sqlstudent');
module.exports={
    getAllData:function(cb){
        cb(sql.fetchData());
    }
}
```

sqlstudent.js

```
module.exports={
    fetchData:function(err){
        if(err)
         console.log(err);
        else{
            return {name : " praveen "};
        }
    }
}
```

Change your code like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can just return the object from "sqlstudent.js".

**return json({name : " praveen "});** This is mistake. 
just write: return {name : " praveen "}